# Wordpress comment, SMTP error page

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, comments

I recently implemented a blog on my site using a custom post type. When I activate commenting, if I'm logged in, the comments go through fine, but I log out and test the commenting, it takes me to an SMTP error page which reads as:

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 mx.google.com ESMTP u1sm13031122oee.8 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 mx.google.com ESMTP u1sm13031122oee.8 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP u1sm13031122oee.8 - gsmtp
```

Plus about fifty more lines.

It seems there is an error in trying to send the email to an address that is not "local".

The code for the custom post type is as follows:

```
<?php

function my_custom_post_articles() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Articles', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Article', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Article' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Article' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Article' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Articles' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Article' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Articles' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Articles found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Articles found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Articles'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our articles and article specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'articles', $args );    
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_articles' );



?>
```

Comment: Can you give more details on: "using a custom post type"? Did you create the custom type?

Comment: Yes I created the custom post type. Is there something that needs to be done when creating the post type in regards to SMTP and comments?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But there is a certain procedure for creating custom post types. Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Do you have the same error with other post types?

Comment: Added code to question. Yes, I am getting the same error on other post types as well, though it is custom as well, but was set up by the wordpress theme creator. I do not have any normal posts to comment on to check. This must be a mail server problem?

Comment: Code looks fine. Try narrowing down to the cause. Did you try another theme?

Comment: Aha, I found out the problem. It's kind of silly. I was having SMTP problems a while ago and had "activate debugging" checked and forgot to uncheck it, so it was debugging every time it tried to send an email. Thanks for you help!